# pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH to wsgi

Tags: linux, apache

I'm deploying a flask site on a hosting which has two versions of libpq.so. First one is installed in /usr/lib which is used by localy installed psycopg2 library by default: 
    ldd _psycopg.so linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff63b4f000) libpq.so.5 =>        /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fde5d775000)

unfortunatelly this version has no lo_truncate64 symbol: 
    python run.app 
    undefined symbol: lo_truncate64

but when i'm starting site using localy installed correct version of libpq.so it's starts okay: 
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/b/.local/lib

i have no administrative rights and can't restart or reconfigure apache how can i pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH to wsgi script? 
    SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/b/.local/lib 
is not working

Answer (score 1):

Answer is patchelf tool. It could change rpath inside elf file.